# Cost of cache coherency/sharing data across multiple cores?

Tags: architecture, performance, multithreading, optimization, cpu

If I have two CPU cores, one is writing a particular cache line and the other core wishes to

1. Read
2. Write

the same cache line, what are the costs (in cycles) for doing so?

I am a little unsure whether the Read-For-Ownership request has to propagate through the L1 and L2 caches on its way to the CPU-which-already-owns-the-cache-line. When the cacheline is retrieved and returned, I know we pass through the L3, L2 and L1 caches, because all three need to be populated with the updated cache line.

Comment: Related: [Software Techniques for Shared Cache Multi-Core Systems](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/software-techniques-for-shared-cache-multi-core-systems).

Comment: What type of CPU core, on what kind of bus?  Are they on the same die?